# Plugins to guide inexperienced users: updating shapefiles and managing data

Tags: qgis, data, plugins

I am attempting to find a way to block adding features while certain attributes are not yet added. This would be useful in order to guide inexperienced clients and employees with the process of adding entities and updating shapefiles while managing data. For example, add feature in edition mode disables 'Okay' button until certain attributes are filled. Any suggestions on either a plug-in that exists or where to start for programming one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out about the Custom Forms feature on QGIS. This was just what I needed.

More info found here:
http://nathanw.net/2011/09/05/qgis-tips-custom-feature-forms-with-python-logic/